# pass stack variable to function that takes a std::shared pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

If I have a global variable, or a stack variable can I pass it to a function that takes a `std::shared_ptr` with a templated class like this:

```
template<class T> class shared_ptr_stack:public std::shared_ptr<T> {
    public:
    shared_ptr_stack(T * target):std::shared_ptr<T>(target, [](T * t){}){};
    };
};
```

The goal would be to avoid destructing or deleting memory when there are no references left.  The code compiles and works in tests, but I am concerned I am invoking undefined behaviour or some other negative issue.

Comment: If your objective is to avoid a heap allocation then you haven’t achieved it because the shared_ptr still needs to allocate its control structure. And if you aren’t trying to avoid a heap allocation… why not just use the heap instead of the stack?

Comment: Public inheritance from a class not designed for it is a bad idea. You could instead introduce a global function `make_shared_stack<T>` that constructs a `shared_ptr` with no-op deleter.

Comment: That would be undefined behavior waiting to happen. That function probably takes `shared_ptr` for a reason - I'd suspect it stashes the pointer somewhere for later use. You plan to hand to it a local variable that will soon go out of scope, rendering that stashed pointer dangling.

Comment: @Eugene If a class derived from a class that is not designed for inheritance has no members, just helper functions what sort of problems can arise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function that takes a shared ptr has the right to make your data persist indefinitely.  It can pass your data to different structures, threads, whatever.

Your code means that the data becomes trash when the stack frame goes out of scope, or at static destruction time, either of which can be before the last shared ptr copy dies.

An API taking a shared ptr is asking for that right.  You are lying to it.

Other than that, your code is fine.  I would use a factory function instead of a subclass however.  You could also use aliasing ctor of shared ptr to get some RAII based reporting.